# How can I select the rows that have only one element non nan value and all the the rest are NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract from a dataframe the rows that have only element no-Nan and the rest are None.
For example :

```
    A   B   C
0   NaN NaN   2
1 NaN   3 NaN
2 NaN   4   5
3 NaN NaN NaN
```

For this example of dataframe it should return the first row.
I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
df_table.isnull(df_table[cols]).all(axis=1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: why shouldn't it return the two first rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum` instead of `all`:

```
df.loc[df.notnull().sum(1)==1]
```

To get the non-nan elements, you can use, for example, `max`:

```
df.loc[df.notnull().sum(1)==1].max(1)
```

or

```
df.loc[df.notnull().sum(1)==1].ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
```

which gives:

```
0    2.0
1    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: How can I print the no-nan element?

Comment: When I try to print the non element it return NAN

Comment: When I try to print the non element it return NAN

Comment: @CarmenMitru I got `2.0` and `3.0` as updated in the answer.

Comment: yes sorry it works for integer but I have strings. How can I do for strings?